# IS NULL for variables in dynamic sql

Tags: sql, dynamic, view, isnull

How can i dynamically create a view of rows with NULL values? There's a mistake in 'is null'.

```
insert into table1( name, surname,k) values ('Linkin', 'Park' , NULL)
insert into table1( name, surname,k) values ('Jay', 'Z', NULL)

declare @view varchar(60)='table1'
declare @col varchar(150)='name, patronymic, surname'
declare @column_name varchar(20)='k'
declare @new_tname varchar(70)='table1'
exec(N'create view['+ @view +']as select '+@col+' from [' + @new_tname +
']where ['+ @column_name + '] is null')
```

Comment: Your view and your table have the same name.

Comment: it's not so important. my question is about 'is null'.

Comment: Your SQL works just fine if you create a table called `table1` with columns `name, patronymic, surname` and set variables correctly (change `@view` value to something unique like 'myView' and `column_name` to existing table column like 'surname')

Comment: Is it prohibited to create a view with the same name?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you cannot create a VIEW with the same name as the table. Also make sure the table contains all the columns in you @col variable.

View the SQL Fiddle I created to see the select from the VIEW executing successfully: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c5c60/4